# How to return T2 name based on data from T1?

Tags: mysql, sql

T1 **game**

```
ID   IDC  POWER  HP      LTIME
01   234  NULL   NULL    -1
02   235  NULL   NULL    -1
03   236  312    213     -1
04   237  111    111      1
05   238  331    111      4
```

T2 **heroes**

```
ID   NAME
234  TOM
235  JEK
236  MAX
237  JIZ
238  ZAK
```

T1 IDC = ID from T2

I need to return all heroes that have anything except null in POWER or in HP with LTIME != -1

Query should return ID and NAME from T2 for that heroes.

In this example query should return: 236 MAX

I tried this:

```
SELECT heroes.ID, heroes.name
FROM heroes
WHERE LTIME in ( SELECT * FROM game WHERE LTIME IS NOT NULL and POWER or HP != -1)
```

Comment: What is a "hero"?  There is no such thing in the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff fixed T2 name

Comment: Note that the subquery is supposed to return only 1 column here. `*` will give you all columns.

Comment: @Akina sorry, fixed now

Comment: You have tables `heroes` and `game`. But your query uses `players`. Where is that?

Comment: @Barmar fixed Im sorry

Comment: *In this example query should return: 236 MAX* o_O its LTIME = -1...

Comment: Why do you check `LTIME IS NOT NULL`? You said you want `LTIME != -1`

Comment: @Barmar fixed now, sorry again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WHERE` condition in the subquery is not correct. `0` is not the same thing as `NULL`. And `POWER or HP != 0` is not the way you test both columns. You have to write `POWER IS NOT NULL AND HP IS NOT NULL`.

There's no `LTIME` column in the `heroes` table, so you can't test that in the main query. The subquery should return IDs, you can test that. But it's generally better to use `JOIN` instead of `IN`.

```
SELECT h.ID, h.name
FROM heroes AS h
JOIN game AS g on h.id = g.idc
WHERE g.ltime = -1 AND g.power IS NOT NULL AND g.hp IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Sorry for bugs in data, this query is what I was looking for with fix != - 1 to = -1, thank you <3

Comment: Your description was confusing. I read "with LTIME != -1" the other way.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest, i don't understand why you say that in your example the query should return 236 MAX... Unless you want LTIME=-1.

Anyway, i think that the best thing to do is using a JOIN:

```
SELECT heroes.ID, heroes.NAME
FROM heroes 
JOIN game
ON heroes.ID=game.IDC
WHERE (game.POWER IS NOT NULL AND game.HP IS NOT NULL) 
AND game.LTIME=-1
```

This query should return 236 MAX, but fix the WHERE clause if it's not what you want.